# Android: How can I pass a time value from one activity to another?

Tags: android, android-intent, time

I have two `Time` values in one of my activity and I have set the time to current time like this:

```
StartTime.setToNow();   
EndTime.setToNow();
```

I want to pass the values of `StartTime` and `EndTime` to another activity, but all I am getting is year 1970 ... something something which is obviously wrong.

I am passing the data with an `Intent` like this:

```
 Intent intent1 = new Intent (Localisation.this, Quiz.class);
 intent1.putExtra("StartTime", StartTime.second);
 intent1.putExtra("EndTime", EndTime.gmtoff);
 startActivity(intent1);
```

Can you tell me how to do it correctly?

Comment: What about toMillis() and passing that value? In the other activity you could pass that value to set() and you should be good.

Comment: I will try and get back to you.

Comment: thank you that really solve my problem! Can I now used the passed data in a way that I want to get the difference of StartTime-EndTime?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. You could calculate the difference by subtracting both times as milliseconds.

Comment: yes but I get an error: The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) android.text.format.Time, android.text.format.Time

Comment: You cannot subtract two time objects, you could do this: startTime.toMillis(false) - endTime.toMillis(false). Then you will have to figure out yourself how many days, hours, etc. the difference is.

Comment: i think your date format is not good then you can try to search SimpleDateFormate on google.

Comment: naah what Roysten suggested did the trick for me and it works fine now even I can calculate the time difference but thanks for you observation ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of java.util.Calendar I recommend you to use third part libraries for different actions with date or time objects.
For example Joda Time.
DateTime object from this library implements Serializable so you can pass value like this

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(); 
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class); 
i.putExtra("date", dt); 
startActivity(i);
```

And second Activity

```
Intent i = getIntent(); 
DateTime dt = (DateTime) i.getSerializableExtra("date");
```

With Joda Time library you can get the differences between two time objects and many other things.

Answer (score 0):

An example based on some of the comments that were added to the original question:

First `Activity`:

```
Date date = StartTime;

Intent launch = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putLong("start_time", date.getTime());
launch.putExtras(extras);
```

Second `Activity`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
Date date = new Date(extras.getLong("start_time"));
```